# Uniform random point in the unit ball

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $(X,Y,Z)$ be a uniformly random point in the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. That is, $(X,Y,Z)$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ whose pdf is given by

$$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}\frac{3}{4\pi} & x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\leq 1\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I would like to find the marginal pdf of $X$. I am able to compute the marginal pdf of $(X,Y)$ is a fairly straightforward way:

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)  =  \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^{2}-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}-y^{2}}}\frac{3}{4\pi}dz=\frac{3}{2\pi}\sqrt{1-x^{2}-y^{2}}
$$

when $x$ and $y$ are such that $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq1$ and $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ otherwise. However, when I go to compute $f_{X}(x)$ I naturally want to integrate the above pdf $f_{X,Y}$ with respect to $y$ by computing

$$f_{X}(x)=\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\frac{3}{2\pi}\sqrt{1-x^{2}-y^{2}}\,dy$$

However computing this integral is unpleasant to say the least. Is there a simpler way of computing $f_{X}$?

Comment: What are limits of the first integral?

Comment: I had them written incorrectly. They should be correct now.

Comment: Let $1 - x^2 = a^2$. Then use $y = a \sin \theta$. The limits for $\theta$ would become $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ and the resulting expression is easy to solve. I think this should do it.

Comment: Your integral isn't so hard:  $\frac{3}{4} \left(1-x^2\right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral isn't so hard:  It reduces to:

$$\int\limits_0^k \sqrt{b - y^2}\ dy$$

(because the integrand is symmetric with respect to $y \leftrightarrow -y$)

Look it up!

The final answer is:

$$\frac{3}{4} (1 - x^2)$$

Comment: Ah, it seems I need to review my calculus. Thank you.